# I am having trouble locating SDK for node.js on the ibm cloud platform was it deprecated or renamed?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

When i run a search for SDK for node.js i get **Node.js Microservice with Express.js** and **Node.js Web App with Express.js** as the only listings. I am following a course on the ibm.dna platform any assistance would be appreciated, i simply want to know if the service still exists and has been renamed or it has been deprecated.

Comment: Can you show us what you're seeing?

Comment: Do you mean Node.js SDK for Cloud Foundry on IBM Cloud?

Comment: What is the URL to the ibm.dna platform course?

Comment: @data_henrik do you have a link for it?

Comment: @PowellQuiring https://developer.ibm.com/digitalnation/africa/my-dashboard/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has indeed changed. Previously you could go to catalog and search for "Node.js". Now you need to search and select "Cloud Foundry", then "Create" for Public Applications, after which, you can select runtime "SDK for Node.js".

Answer (score 0):

The ready to deploy SDKs for Cloud Foundry Public on IBM Cloud were moved to the [category Starter Kits in the catalog](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog?category=starterkits). There you can find Node.js with Express.